# Test for network connectivity from various hosts to one specific host via ssh and telnet

Tags: ssh, aix, telnet

I am trying to see if a port is opened for a list of hostnames/IP's, and I used a simple script like this one to ssh to each host and capture the output.

```
for i in `cat $1`
do ssh $i "sleep 5 | telnet 11.22.33.44 123"
done
```

This is throwing a "No environment-specific terminal time" error because Telnet is designed to be an interactive tool to interact with a smart terminal.

How can I go around this, knowing that I cannot use `nc` command as it's not available on Unix AIX systems?

Please note that some hosts will reply with `Connected to 11.22.33.44. Escape character is ^]` and that means there is connectivity while others will freeze at `Trying ...` meaning that there is no connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since perl is installed by default, one way would be to ssh to the intermediate host and ask it to run perl, with the perl program provided as a here-document:

```
for host in $(< "$1")
do

  ssh "$host" perl << 'EOF'
use IO::Socket;
my $handle = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        PeerAddr => '11.22.33.44',
        PeerPort => 123,
        Proto    => 'tcp',
        Timeout  => 5)
    or die "Failed\n";
close $handle;
print "Success\n";
EOF

done
```

The script attempts to connect to the given IP and port over TCP; if it fails, you'll get the `Failed` message, but if it succeeds, it immediately closes the connection and prints `Success`.  This uses the `$(< ...)` syntax to read from the filename given by the first parameter; just like `cat`, this scheme assumes that none of the filenames have any characters from `$IFS` in them (spaces, tabs, or newlines by default). I've also quoted the loop variable (here, `host`), to prevent problems if any of the input file contents contain shell globbing characters like `*`, `?`, or `[`.

Comment: Getting `telnetTest[19] :/tmp/sh78123465.13: cannot create` when running with my user and asking for password when running with sudo rights e.g. `sudo ksh telnetTest hostList`

Comment: Why are you running it with sudo?

Comment: To see what happens  when it **can** write to /tmp because my user wasn't allowed. Using my nonroot user account to run this script should allow ssh access to the `hostList` through already stored keys on both machines

Comment: Long story short, this was exactly what I was looking for. I have solved the permission issue by, well, adding permission. Still don't understand why this scrip tries to write on /tmp but at least it's working